# Renaming columns of matrix based on pattern

Tags: r

I'm new to R and have encountered a problem when wanting to rename my columns. This is my matrix and I want to rename each column as gene 1, gene 2 etc.

`count.data <-  matrix(data = 1, nrow = 3, ncol = 5)`

I've seen some example of using colnames() = c() but I don't know how to apply it to my matrix. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is a good reason to use `sprintf`, which allows you to print a formatted string.

`%d` in the first argument is replaced by the sequence of integers in the second argument.

```
colnames(count.data) = sprintf("gene%d", 1:ncol(count.data))
```

```
     gene1 gene2 gene3 gene4 gene5
[1,]     1     1     1     1     1
[2,]     1     1     1     1     1
[3,]     1     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: That seems to work the first time I run it but when I do it a second time it is affected by later code and doesn't give back a matrix of ones

Comment: Without knowing any of the other code, I can't help you.

Comment: I solved it, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
use colnames() method. Syntax: colnames(df) <-
c(new_col1_name,new_col2_name,new_col3_name).
```

You can find a detailed article:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/change-column-name-of-a-given-dataframe-in-r/